# Many identical Apache Tomcat children being spawned automatically at startup time

Tags: apache, tomcat, configuration, process

I have no applications installed under webapps except the tomcat "manager/"

Every time I run ./startup.sh to start tomcat and I open htop (an advanced version of top) I see like 16 new processes spawned as children of the main apache tomcat process. Here is how all the processes (children + parent) running commands look like in htop:

```
/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_29/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.33/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManage -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/loca/tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.33/endorsed -classpath /home/dhruba/tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.33/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/loca/tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.33 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/loca/tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.33 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.33/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Any idea on why they are created and how to control this number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those aren't processes, those are threads. You only have a single process.

Comment: Thx, Yes they are threads. you are right. Any idea on how to control their number? or the maximum thread tomcat is allowed to create?

Comment: Most threads are used by the connectors for processing requests and limited by the maxThreads attribute of the connector in server.xml. There are a handful of other threads created as well and 16 doesn't seem like an unreasonable number to me. A thread dump will tell you what they are.