# tomcat deploy webapp many times

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, host, deploying

I'm using apache 2 and tomcat 7 to run my webapps..

When I start Tomcat, its log shows that the same webapp has deployed many times..

```
:
Deploying web application directory /var/www/web/www.mysite.com
:
:
Deploying web application directory /var/www/web/www.mysite.com
:
:
```

the file `server.xml` looks like :

```
.............
<Host name="www.mysite.com" appBase="/var/www/web" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false">
    <Context path="" docBase="www.mysite.com" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
</Host>
<Host name="www.mysitetwo.com" appBase="/var/www/web" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false">
    <Context path="" docBase="www.mysitetwo.com" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
</Host>
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">  
..........
```

How can avoid that?

Comment: It's probably logging that for every http child that starts up.

Comment: could you be more clear please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292844/many-identical-apache-tomcat-children-being-spawned-automatically-at-startup-tim

Comment: ok clear but i get this error on startup :

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /www.mysite.com threw load() exception javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: ...

and i think that this error is caused by the multiple deployments..

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. I have 4 hosts, one context per host, and each Context has deployed 4 times.

The host deploys the explicit contexts defined in `server.xml` and the contexts in Application Base Directory.

The Application Base Directory is defined in `<Host appBase="dir">` tag. The default is:

`$CATALINA_BASE/webapps`

If two or more hosts are using the same Application Base Directory, each subdirectory in Application Base will be deployed many time as the number of hosts.

I solved the problem keeping the `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps` empty and put each context out of Application Base Directory.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html

Comment: I'm experiencing this problem. In my case, app's are loaded at least 7 times. Could you tell me how did you configured the *appBase* parameter in your server.xml file?? Did you use a different appBase directory for each host? or did you left that parameter in blank? (appBase="")

Comment: This site discourage you from saying "thank you", however, you saved me a lot of time and i don't think I could figure out what you did on my own. So THANKS A LOT!!!!

Comment: Thanks from me also. This has got to be a bug - still not fixed in 2021.